# CollectionView with multiple cell templates (use of undeclared type, <typeName> is ambiguous for type lookup in this context)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In one of my collection views I have to use two cell templates for different sections. For both cells I use .xib files. I have two custom classes: 
`OverprintsCollectionViewCell` and `OverprintsCollectionViewDetailCell`.

In the view controller where the said collection view is located in `` I use section index to decide which template to use. The code looks like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView is OverprintsCollectionView {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "twoLblCell", for: indexPath) as? OverprintsCollectionViewCell {

                // Swift compiler message in the line above:  "Use of undeclared type 'OverprintsCollectionViewCell'"

                // cell setup  

                return cell
            }
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "twoLblDetailCell", for: indexPath) as? OverprintsCollectionViewDetailCell {

                // Swift compiler message in the line above:  "'OverprintsCollectionViewDetailCell' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context"

                // cell setup  

                return cell
            }
        }

    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

App builds and runs successfully despite those errors. 
I've never used a collection view with more than one cell template before and I'm not really sure what could be causing this problem.

Some of the things I've checked after a little bit of googling: 
- Both files (`OverprintsCollectionViewCell.swift` and `OverprintsCollectionViewDetailCell.swift`) have properly set targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking everything twice (all identifiers, targets etc.), cleaning the project, relaunching Xcode what actually helped was deleting my project's derived data.